# new tires for schwinn phocus 700C

Tags: road-bike, tire

Was wondering what heavy duty tires someone would recommend.  I have been using stock tires and they have blown a leak a number of times in the last six months.  Love the bike, just want more sturdy and fatter tires.  I live in pothole central and want something that can handle it.

[http://www.amazon.com/Schwinn-Phocus-Bicycle-Black-18-Inch/dp/B00AWNI07K/ref=cm_cd_ql_qh_dp_t](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AWNI07K)

Any recommendations?  Thanks!

Comment: Panaracer Ribmo - Not the lightest, but these things are durable, awesome flat protection. Available in tons of sizes. I'd recommend the 700x28c for a road bike.

Comment: Use belted tires.  I've only had two punctures since I switched to Kevlar belted tires many years back.  Prior to that had about one a week.  And inflate to at least the sidewall max pressure.

Comment: From the picture, its hard to tell what the stock tires are (700x25c maybe?), but I think DRH is right - belted tires, proper tire and tube installation and proper tire inflation are the way to go. It doesn't look like it would clear anything significantly larger than stock.

Answer (score 1):

Potholes cause impact punctures (also called *pinch punctures* or *snakebites*) when the force of an impact is sufficient to compress the tyre all the way to the rim.

Options to reduce the risk:

1. Increase tyre pressure
2. Reduce impact energy by reducing weight or reducing speed
3. **Use larger tyres**, which would increase the distance between the rims and potential hazards and could also be more comfortable.
4. Use your arms and legs as suspension to absorb some of the impact force.
5. Ensure your weight is not excessively biased to the front or rear of the bicycle.

Measure your frame and fork to check your maximum tyre size:

- Slick bicycle tyres tend to have circular cross-sections so the tyre should be as high above the rim as their width. (Unless your chosen tyre has a thick extra layer of rubber to prevent penetration by glass and thorns, e.g Schwalbe's "Plus" models)
- Regulation EN 4.10.2 "Wheel/Tyre Assembly - Clearance” states a minimum tire clearance of 6mm between any part of the frame or fork. I suggest you maintain this clearance.

Answer (score 0):

On a cyclocross/hybrid commuter I'm running Continental Contacts, and they have been decent to good. (running 700x28's)

https://www.conti-online.com/www/bicycle_de_en/themes/city/Allround/CONTACT_en.html

Because of the wear I'm thinking of switching to Top Contact II's. Pretty spendy tho.

Disclaimer I have a 'trekking' bike tire bias, In general I'm not concerned with weight, reliable is far more important to me.

Also make sure you get the right innertube size for the with of your tire.